# Dreamweaver Spry Menu Vertical Navigation

Tags: menu, dreamweaver, spry

I am unable to set the Menu in this format:

Menu1  SubMenu1.1  Submenu 1.1.1

somehow I have changed some setting and it looks like this:

```
Menu1 
     SubMenu1.1
               Submenu 1.1.1
```

How can I get it back to a complete horizontal submenu ?

Comment: i dont see any difference between your two menus

Comment: apologies, this should be clear now

Comment: I tried the below and in Dreamweaver submenu shows fine however in Firefox and IE they show incorrect:                                 ul.MenuBarVertical ul
{
 margin: -100% 0 0 95%;}